# Using input in Mat-table listing makes UI Unresponsive

Tags: html, angular, typescript, sass, angular-material

I am adding input fields in material table listing which makes UI slow in adding 30 records and more than that UI become unresponsive

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz example with some code in it? Have you already tried to use virtual-scrolling provided by Angular CDK (https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview#virtual-scrolling)?

Comment: yes I am using virtual scrolling and also paginator but this is not helping me when I remove the input fields its working fine on 5000+ records @FabianStrathaus

Comment: Well, to be able to debug what could be the issue, you should provide some code for us to look at.